# How to change cursor type on nsbox and nsimage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am using xamarin.mac to make an cocoa application. I have box on view controller, 
i want whenever mouse comes over on that box it changes in to hand just like in nsbutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1st: NSView Subclass

Create a subclass of the `NSView` and define what you what to happen in the `MouseEntered` / `MouseExited` overrides. In this case pushing and popping a `NSCursor.ClosedHandCursor` from the cursor stack.

```
public partial class MyCustomImageView : NSImageView
{
    [Export("initWithCoder:")]
    public MyCustomImageView(NSCoder coder) : base(coder) { }
    public MyCustomImageView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }

    NSCursor cursor;

    [Export("mouseEntered:")]
    public override void MouseEntered(NSEvent theEvent)
    {
        cursor = NSCursor.ClosedHandCursor;
        cursor.Push();
        base.MouseEntered(theEvent);
    }

    [Export("mouseExisted:")]
    public override void MouseExited(NSEvent theEvent)
    {
        base.MouseExited(theEvent);
        cursor?.Pop();
    }

}
```

#### 2nd: NSTrackingArea

Now you can define a `NSTrackingArea` that will activate the mouse entered and exited handlers. Assuming `MyImageView` is an instance/outlet of your NSView subclass and then add that tracking area to the view (`AddTrackingArea()`).

```
var ta = new NSTrackingArea(MyImageView.Bounds, NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways | NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited, MyImageView, null);
MyImageView.AddTrackingArea(ta);
```